# How do I know whether tar really pass XZ_OPT to xz?

Tags: tar, xz

What I am doing:

```
XZ_OPT='-T0 -9 -vv' tar -vvcJf ~/backup.tar.xz ...FILES
```

I doubt if `tar` really pass the given options, I have tried those things:

1. I used `-vv` in `XZ_OPT`, but there is no message from `xz` in the output, neither `--verbose`
2. I also use`ps aux | grep xz` to see if `tar` will `spawn` another process for `xz`, but I didn't see that `tar` create any process.

### Questions

1. Does `XZ_OPT` environment really work? How to verify it?
2. Why can't I find `xz` processes during `tar` execution? Does `tar` really spawn process to compress files?

### Environment

```
$ xz --version
xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.5
liblzma 5.2.5
$ tar --version
bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.6
```

Comment: What OS are you running? I can see `bsdtar`, it may very well be possible only GNU tar accepts XZ_OPT...

Comment: Also, you should show us an example output you are getting, if there is any, that is.

Answer (score 12):

> 1. Does `XZ_OPT` environment really work? How to verify it?

Pass something invalid to it:

```
% XZ_OPT='--this-wont-work' tar -cJf foo.tar.xz foo
xz: unrecognized option '--this-wont-work'
xz: Try `xz --help' for more information.
tar: foo.tar.xz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

> 2. Why can't I find `xz` processes during tar execution? Does `tar` really spawn process to compress files?

From the output above, it looks like it does. Does your archive take long enough to create for the process to last? `ps aux | grep xz` and `pgrep -fa xz` both show `xz` processes for me.

---

In all likelihood, `tar` won't show output from the programs it calls unless they fail. Otherwise, they could add uncontrolled noise to the output which wasn't asked for from `tar` itself.

Comment: That's weired. I get exit code 0 after run `XZ_OPT='--this-wont-work' tar -cJf backup.tar.xz backup.txt`, and output nothing.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Fzu309V.png

Comment: @Quasímodo Still the same https://i.imgur.com/SHV6Ue2.png no luck :(

Comment: @Weihang what version of Fish are you using?

Comment: @WeihangJian seems you're using bsdtar. My tests used GNU tar. I'll test bsdtar and see what comes up. Bsdtar might be using the xz library directly.

Comment: With `--use-compress-program`, it works!  https://i.imgur.com/y5SesQV.png

Comment: Not quite sure why it works but I think without `--use-compress-program`, bsdtar would try to use it's built-in compressor and it won't even concern XZ_OPT. Need more time for investigation.

Comment: @WeihangJian yes, my [`man bsdtar`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/libarchive/bsdtar.1.en#BUGS) says "The compression and decompression is implemented internally, so there may be insignificant differences between the compressed output generated by
`tar -czf - file`
and that generated by
`tar -cf - file | gzip`" [and](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/libarchive/bsdtar.1.en#EXAMPLES) "you can set the compression level used by gzip or xz compression:
`tar -czf file.tar --options='compression-level=9'`.

Comment: @WeihangJian:  Another way to be sure what's happening is to trace system calls, like `strace -f -efork,execve tar ...`.  (Different kernels have different names for their trace tools; `strace` works on Linux, and maybe some other OSes.)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you used, in most shells, will create that environment variable and "export" it.  After that, unless tar *explicitly deletes it from the environment*, every child program will see it.

I do see it having some effect.  Contrast this:

```
$ XZ_OPT='-T0 -9 -vv' tar -cJf junk.tar.xz ~/.config
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
xz: Filter chain: --lzma2=dict=64MiB,lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,mode=normal,nice=64,mf=bt4,depth=0
xz: Using up to 4 threads.
xz: 4,997 MiB of memory is required. The limiter is disabled.
xz: Decompression will need 65 MiB of memory.
  100 %   2,541.8 KiB / 5,930.0 KiB = 0.429                   0:01
```

with this (where I removed the `-vv`):

```
$ XZ_OPT='-T0 -9' tar -cJf junk.tar.xz ~/.config
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```